# How to standardize values in a column based on grouping by two other columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure this is a really simple thing but I'm very new to R.

I have three columns, one with values I need standardized, one with age groups and one with gender. I want a new column where the standardization is made by agegroup and sex, for example 18-28 year old females have different scores than 18-28 year old males.

R
def function(foo):
    print(foo)

```
       agegroup gender value
1      68-90      M           0.55140187
2      38-48      M           0.93333333
3      18-28      F           0.43283582
4       0-18      F           0.00001000
5       0-18      M           0.00001000
6      28-38      F           0.04081633
7      18-28      F           0.37837838
8      28-38      M           0.57142857
9      28-38      F           0.34183673
10     18-28      F           0.37804878
11     28-38      M           0.53571429
12      0-18      M           0.00001000
```

I have tried using dplyr

```
df %>% group_by(agegroup, gender) %>% mutate(scaled = scale(values))
```

The grouping is not happening by gender as well as age group. I think I have to use summarise but I'm not sure how to.

I'm sorry if this is really simple or not well explained, as I said I'm very new to this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: could you please explain a bit your dataset, and how are the variables that you want to use?

Comment: Try `df %>% dplyr::group_by(agegroup, gender) %>% mutate(scaled = scale(values))`

Comment: I can't replicate any issue with my own synthetic data. Using your code I was able to scale based on `gender` and `agegroup` without a hitch. I checked the result by first filtering the dataframe by `gender` and `agegroup` and then scaling, and the results were the same. Have you maybe misunderstood the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done seems to be right. You cannot use `summarise()` as it returns a single value and not a vector.

From your question, I'm not sure if you want to scale the value for each group or find the sum of value for each group. I've sampled both the cases.

```r
# Sample data
  age sex values
1 <10   M      1
2 <10   M      2
3 >10   F      3
4 >10   F      4
5 >10   M      5

# Scaling value
df %>% group_by(age, sex) %>% mutate(std_value = scale(values))
  age   sex   values std_value
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 <10   M          1    -0.707
2 <10   M          2     0.707
3 >10   F          3    -0.707
4 >10   F          4     0.707
5 >10   M          5   NaN

# Sum of values
df %>% group_by(age, sex) %>% mutate(sum_value = sum(values))
  age   sex   values sum_value
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 <10   M          1         3
2 <10   M          2         3
3 >10   F          3         7
4 >10   F          4         7
5 >10   M          5         5
```